# How to create a full rainbow background

Tags: html, css, background, background-color, color-picker

I am creating a custom color picker, and I do not know how to create a rainbow gradient background color. I would like to do the background without javascript if possible. Can someone please guide me on this?

Comment: Are you saying something along the lines of a person picks X amount of colors and then it generates a linear-gradient that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following html code,

```css
#rainbow{
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, Red , Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, Violet);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="rainbow"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can also change this to make it from top to bottom

```
#rainbow{
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do this.

```css
.container{
  background:linear-gradient(90deg, Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo,violet);
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

if it helps you let me know